# pattern to root out email addresses

Tags: php, mysql, regex, database

I have a text document with a slew of email addresses which I converted from a pdf.
here is an example of of what it looks like:

```
name1;someone@awebite1.com;;;
name2;someone@awebite2.com;;;
name3;someone@awebite3.com;;;
name4;someone@awebite4.com;;;
name5;someone@awebite5.com;;;
```

etc... 600+ contacts

anyone know to to write a simple php pattern/expression/regex I can use to separate the name and email one by one so I can put in database?

the database of course would be a simple: id | contact | email

any help would be gladly appreciated!

I forgot to mention, I would like to do it in php. I will incorporate the code into a form for future usage.

Comment: your data looks like properly formatted CSV to me - a *very* common format for import/export spreadsheets/dbtables.

Comment: The command-line program that processes tabular text data. You can split on semicolon and take what you want from whatever fields

Comment: @lc. I was looking for a way to do it with simply php. I get these every month or two. I want to make a form I an just copy it into and let php do it's magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, you can split a string using the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function..

```
$parts = explode(';', $inputString);
```

The returned array contains each part separated by `;`.

For this, each line in your text document has to be given as `inputString`. So loop through the array returned by

```
preg_split('/\\n/',$docContent)
```

and call `explode` with each element. The above `preg_split`returns an array with each line of the input as an element.

**Combining both**,

```
$lines = preg_split('/\\n/',$docContent);
foreach($lines as $line) {
   $parts = explode(';', $line);
   //$parts[0] is name and $parts[1] is email. ignore remaining elements
}
```

**Note :** I have only a little knowledge in php. There may be better code.

Comment: not sure but im getting an error: `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\test.php on line 436
Array`

Comment: sorry I see what I was doing wrong. I was was trying to echo $parts which is an array. but I was able to see what was going on with `print_r`.  but I'm still at a standstill. how would I make the contact a variable and the email a variable. I need to run a query to insert each contact and each associated email into the db.

Comment: @Keezy $parts[0] gives name and $parts[1] gives email. Is this what you asked?

Comment: using the above code the array goes from [0] all the way to [1280]. `Array ( [0] => exampleUK.com [1] => tonym@exampleUK.com [2] => [3] => [4] => j1200 [5] => info@j1200.com [6] => [7] => [8] => 210example [9] => 210example@gmail.com [10] => [11] => ...etc)`

Comment: @Keezy With each element in the array returned by `preg_split('/\\n/',$docContent)` as `$inputString`, apply the `explode` function as above.

Comment: still couldn't figure it out. where do i put the second line of code? `explode(';', $inputString);` is making each semicolon an element so using that code gives this: `name1;someone@awebite1.com;;;` four elements... one for name, one for email, than one for each of the following semicolons

Comment: for one line alone I would get an array similar to `Array ( [0] => exampleUK.com [1] => tonym@exampleUK.com [2] => [3] => )`

Comment: this array's first element is name and second one is email. combined code is added.

Comment: if there is a better code I'd love to see it but this works PERFECT for what I need right now.. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'yourFile'
INTO TABLE yourTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY ';;;\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that by "contact" you mean the very first field of each line (which says 'contact' for all shown values), something like this will work:

```
cat contacts.txt | awk {'split($2,A,";"); print A[1]"|"$1"|"A[2]}'
```